# How to get parameters from url received in headers?

Tags: node.js, express, http-headers

I am trying to get some parameters from a url that I receive in the headers from a response. To be specific, a host responds with data in headers, not in body.

To get the values from headers I use the following code:

```
let header = req.get('location');
```

Where, 'location' is the 'key' and the 'value' is 'http://examplesite.com/oauth?code=1234&state=4321'.

I need to get the values 'code' and 'state' from the url, is there any solution I could try besides substring(), search(),...? I discard those options because of different uri's and parameteres that can be sent.

I am using nodejs 10 and express 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`url`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html) builtin module. Especially, the [`url.parse()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstring_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) method with `parseQueryString` set to true.

```
var url = require('url');

var stringUrl = req.get('location'); //'http://examplesite.com/oauth?code=1234&state=4321';

var { code, state } = url.parse(stringUrl, true).query;
console.log("Code "+code, "State "+state); //Code 1234 State 4321
```